Langchain's ConversationBufferWindowMemory seems to have everything in memory despite of the configuration
I'm using Langchain's ConversationBufferWindowMemory with k=1, expecting the model to remember only the most recent interaction and not the entire conversation history. However, when I check, I find that older interactions are not being cleared from memory as expected. How can I resolve this issue? 
Even though the conversations are not deleted from the memory the model can't able to answer from the interaction made earlier.
from langchain_ollama import ChatOllama
from langchain.chains.conversation.memory import ConversationBufferWindowMemory
from langchain.chains import ConversationChain

llm = ChatOllama(
    model="llama3-chatqa:latest",
    temperature=0,
)

conversation = ConversationChain(
    llm=llm,
    memory=ConversationBufferWindowMemory(k=1)
)

while True:
    message = input("Human: ")
    if message == "Done":
        break

    # Print the input message
    print("\n \n ########## Input:")
    print(message)

      # Print the current context before invoking the model
    print("########## Context:")
    print(conversation.memory)

    response = conversation.invoke(message)["response"]

    # Print the response
    print("########## AI response:")
    print(response)

If you observe the output below it seems to take my first conversation also in the context.
but the model can't able to answer the question from history even if the memory has everything
Human: my aim is to learn machine learning today 


 ########## Input:
my aim is to learn machine learning today
########## Context:
chat_memory=InMemoryChatMessageHistory(messages=[]) k=1
########## AI response:
 Great! I can help you with that. What specifically would you like to learn about machine learning?


Human: who is the PM of India?
 ########## Input:
who is the PM of India?
########## Context:
chat_memory=InMemoryChatMessageHistory(messages=[HumanMessage(content='my aim is to learn machine learning today', additional_kwargs={}, response_metadata={}), AIMessage(content=' Great! I can help you with that. What specifically would you like to learn about machine learning?', additional_kwargs={}, response_metadata={})]) k=1
########## AI response:
 Prime Minister Narendra Modi


Human: Who is vladmir putin ?
 ########## Input:
Who is vladmir putin ?
########## Context:
chat_memory=InMemoryChatMessageHistory(messages=[HumanMessage(content='my aim is to learn machine learning today', additional_kwargs={}, response_metadata={}), AIMessage(content=' Great! I can help you with that. What specifically would you like to learn about machine learning?', additional_kwargs={}, response_metadata={}), HumanMessage(content='who is the PM of India?', additional_kwargs={}, response_metadata={}), AIMessage(content=' Prime Minister Narendra Modi', additional_kwargs={}, response_metadata={})]) k=1
########## AI response:
 Vladimir Putin


Human: what is my aim for today ?
 ########## Input:
what is my aim for today ?
########## Context:
chat_memory=InMemoryChatMessageHistory(messages=[HumanMessage(content='my aim is to learn machine learning today', additional_kwargs={}, response_metadata={}), AIMessage(content=' Great! I can help you with that. What specifically would you like to learn about machine learning?', additional_kwargs={}, response_metadata={}), HumanMessage(content='who is the PM of India?', additional_kwargs={}, response_metadata={}), AIMessage(content=' Prime Minister Narendra Modi', additional_kwargs={}, response_metadata={}), HumanMessage(content='Who is vladmir putin ?', additional_kwargs={}, response_metadata={}), AIMessage(content=' Vladimir Putin', additional_kwargs={}, response_metadata={})]) k=1
########## AI response:
 Your aim for today is to get up and go about your day.


Even though it has memory all the previous conversations i just passes past k conversations to the model to predict.
The main motto here is to optimize the token size and not the primary memory. 
So i feel it is better to write own code to optimize memory too. 
Revision 1:
Found a new method named trim_message which deletes the older message based on the parameter named token , If token is given as 2 , then only last two convo pairs is taken others are deleted ,I think that is better in terms of memory and token management.
https://python.langchain.com/docs/how_to/chatbots_memory/#trimming-messages
